# Javascript Unexpected identifier Uncaught Syntax Error

Tags: javascript

I am very new to js, and clearly don't know what I'm doing, but am quite frustrated and really appreciate any help, here is what I'm working on:

```
var pop;

var intermission = {
   ogg: "https://ia802300.us.archive.org/24/items/DriveInIntermission13/Drive-inIntermission13.ogv",
   mp4: "https://ia802300.us.archive.org/24/items/DriveInIntermission13/Drive-inIntermission13_512kb.mp4"
};

var vid; 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
   vid = document.querySelector('#tehvidya'); //this is a dom object;

   pop = Popcorn('#tehvidya', {
       frameAnimation: true
   }); 
}



  pop.on()
 "loadedmetadata",
function() {
   pop.play();

   //video has loaded, we now have duration and other metadata
   console.log(pop.duration());
   h1.style.opacity = 0;
});

h1.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
pop.play();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think the error is from this snippet of code....

Comment: can you share the context of the code... where it is placed

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a problem here:

```
  pop.on()
 "loadedmetadata",
function() {
   pop.play();

   //video has loaded, we now have duration and other metadata
   console.log(pop.duration());
   h1.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

I suspect this should have been:

```
pop.on("loadedmetadata",function() {
   pop.play();

   //video has loaded, we now have duration and other metadata
   console.log(pop.duration());
   h1.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

You have an extraneous `)` messing things up.

Also, in this:

```
h1.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
pop.play();
</script>
```

You're missing a `});` before the `</script>`...and possibly other things, but you're certainly missing a close to that function expression.

Comment: I get the same response on chrome's console with that syntax, same error response that is.. Is there a need to define pop or something along those lines?

Comment: Edited to add another syntactic problem.